# Why am i getting this error while trying to open json file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Here is my code. I'm trying to go through all json files in folder, pretty print them and write to output txt file.

```py
import json 
import os

directory = os.listdir('D:/py/NFT/project/output/metadata/') 
for file in directory:
    with open(file) as jsonfile:
        parsed = json.load(jsonfile)
        conv = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
        out = open('outputfile' , 'a')
        out.write(conv)
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "d:\py\NFT\project\m.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open(file) as jsonfile: FileNotFoundError: 
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.json'
```

In a folder there is .json files - 1.json , 2.json, 3.json etc

Comment: And it worked perfect like an hour ago  but with another json files. Same names same folder

Comment: It's because you're just using the filename, not the full file path. If the file isn't in the current working directory (the folder in which the program was started) then it won't know where to find the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns a list of all files in the directory, but just the file names, not the absolute path. When you `open` them, since they're not in the directory your main python file is, there's a problem.

You need to add the absolute path section at the start

```py
import json import os

directory = os.listdir('D:/py/NFT/project/output/metadata/') 
for file in directory:
    with open(f"D:/py/NFT/project/output/metadata/{file}") as jsonfile:
        parsed = json.load(jsonfile)
        conv = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
        out = open('outputfile' , 'a')
        out.write(conv)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not strange at all.  The file names returned by `os.listdir` are just the file names, not the path.  You have to add the path:

```
import json import os
path = 'D:/py/NFT/project/output/metadata/'
for file in os.listdir(path):
     with open(os.path.join(path,file)) as jsonfile:
```

Comment: Thank you! I get it now, I'm a newcomer in programming :)